# How do I know the default options in Sconstruct？

Tags: scons

Is there a way to know what options are available in Environment() in Scons? And what are the default values for these options? For example, there are CC and CXXFLAGS options in Environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since many things are determined at runtime, a simple form of introspection is the best way to find out the available construction variables (and their values) on a given system. For example, to save to a file CVARS here's a quick SConstruct file that can be used:

```
env = Environment()
with open("CVARS", "w") as f:
    print(env.Dump(), file=f)
```